# Iron Condor Profit Probability

Tags: stocks, investing, options, trading

I'm trying to see if I understand Iron Condors correctly and how to assess whether or not the risk is worth it for a given set of circumstances.

The maximum profit on an IC is realized when all options in the spread expire out-of-the-money. Since the absolute value of the delta on an individual option is a good proxy for the probability that it will expire in-the-money, can it also be said that the max profit probability on an Iron Condor is indicated by the leg with the highest delta?

So for example, let's say I have an IC where the short put has the highest delta at -0.36. Does that mean that there is a 64% chance all four legs will expire worthless?

Please note, I understand the delta-as-probability assumption has its flaws.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could be  said that the probability of profit for a short Iron Condor would be the leg with the highest delta.

The probability of touch is about twice the probability of expiring ITM.  Traders tend to adjust their short positions before or when the short leg goes ITM so perhaps consider this number as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "touch"?

Comment: PoT = likelihood of reaching (touching) the strike before expiration.  Google "Probability of Touch" for add'l info.

Comment: So in the example I used in my question (0.36 delta), I have a 74% chance of max profit, but a 72% chance that it hits the strikes? And if I hold until expiration, why do I care if it touches before then, as long as it doesn't stay there?

Comment: If you're going to roll the dice and take whatever expiration gives you then yes,  there's no reason to care if it touches before then, as long as it doesn't stay there. So it touches.  Are ya feeling lucky?  However, if you're going to manage the position in order to minimize risk, you do care, not really much  about the probability number but about P&L.

Comment: So it's useful to know when to exit (or modify) your position. Gotcha. One more thing (maybe this should be a separate question); If I made a strategy of trading ICs with >75% PoP, and a profit/risk ratio of >1, I should find it difficult to lose money over the long haul, correct (albeit a slow way to make money)?

Comment: ICs have 4 legs so that means 4 commissions and 4 B/A spreads that reduce P&L, even more if you adjust. In volatile markets, you're going to lose.  When the underlying is quiet, you're going to win. Can you pick the quiescent ones?  Can you efficiently defend the ones that are volatile?   If you widen the strikes to increase the PoP, the R/R becomes worse.  I'm not trying to discourage you but only to suggest that there are no free lunches.  What's your edge?

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to wrap my head around concepts before I actually invest, so I hadn't factored in commissions and such. But I have made some paper trades, and I've been able to construct ICs with wide strikes and high PoPs that have a higher profit potential than risk potential. The law of large numbers says that if you place lots of those trades, the losses from the losers won't overtake the winners' gains. The wildcards being plane crashes, lying CEOs, data breaches, adverse regulatory actions, and things like that. I get that there's no free lunch though, so this is why I ask.

Comment: Last comment: Short ICs have a higher probability of making a smaller profit and a smaller probability of incurring a large loss.  The law of large numbers (LOLN) is going to even that out and the commissions and slippage is going to make the expected return negative.  The only way to overcome that is consistent superior timing and selection (who has that?) and/or good risk management.  If the LOLN dictated otherwise, why would anyone do any other kind of option trade than this?  Who would take the other side of the trade if the long term return was positive?